# Sed operations are not working or might i am doing it wrong?

Tags: linux, awk, sed

input: text:

```
chrX_143483005-chr6_103649292,chrX_143483110-chr6_103649131 chrX_143483110-chr_6103649147   chrX_143483004-chr6_103649293,chrX_143483110-chr6_103649291,chrX_143483110-chr6_103649053
chrX_143483110-chr_6103649147   chrX_143483005-chr6_103649292,chrX_143483110-chr6_103649131 0
0   chrX_143483005-chr6_103649292,chrX_143483110-chr6_103649131 chrX_143482988-chr6_103649147,chrX_143483004-chr6_103649293,chrX_143483110-chr6_103649291,chrX_143483110-chr6_103649053
chrX_143483005-chr6_103649292,chrX_143483110-chr6_103649131 0   chrX_143483110-chr_6103649147
0   chrX_143483005-chr6_103649292,chrX_143483110-chr6_103649131 chrX_143482988-chr6_103649147,chrX_143483004-chr6_103649293,chrX_143483110-chr6_103649291,chrX_143483110-chr6_103649053
```

Desired output:

```
chrX_143483005-chr6_103649292   chrX_143483110-chr_6103649147   chrX_143483004-chr6_103649293
chrX_143483110-chr_6103649147   chrX_143483005-chr6_103649292   0
0   chrX_143483005-chr6_103649292   chrX_143482988-chr6_103649147
chrX_143483005-chr6_103649292   0   chrX_143483110-chr_6103649147
0 chrX_143483005-chr6_103649292 chrX_143482988-chr6_103649147
```

Tried:

```
## No. of Columns in each line.
awk '{print NF}' tt.txt
3
3
3
3
3
## operation to delete the co-ordinates affiliated with comma.
sed -e 's/\,chr[A-Z0-9]\_[0-9]-chr[A-Z0-9]\_[0-9]*.//g' tt.txt
```

Basically I want to remove co-ordinates just after "," and want to keep only left hands (first one) co-ordinates.

NOTE:
1  In this operation, columns would be the same as input.
2. Comma sepratted co-ordinates are not fixed it can be any columns.
3. Chromosomes can any 1-19, X and Y.

Comment: Please, save a cat's life.  Rather than `cat file | sed 'thing'`, simply `sed 'thing' file`.

Answer (score 4):

Simple enough:

```
$ sed -E 's/,[^ ]+//g' in
chrX_143483005-chr6_103649292 chrX_143483110-chr_6103649147   chrX_143483004-chr6_103649293
chrX_143483110-chr_6103649147   chrX_143483005-chr6_103649292 0
0   chrX_143483005-chr6_103649292 chrX_143482988-chr6_103649147
chrX_143483005-chr6_103649292 0   chrX_143483110-chr_6103649147
0   chrX_143483005-chr6_103649292 chrX_143482988-chr6_103649147
```

The (extended) regular expression `/,[^ ]+/` will match any sequence of a comma followed series of characters which are not a space.

The `sed` command `s` will substutute any matches of the first argument (in this case, the given expression), with the second argument (in this case, nothing); the `g` option to the `s` command says to make that substitution for all matches found rather than merely the first.

Comment: awesome !! thanks
Can you please explain, how its work?

Comment: Not working with this line:
0 chrX_143483005-chr6_103649292,chrX_143483110-chr6_103649131 chrX_143482988-chr6_103649147,chrX_143483004-chr6_103649293,chrX_143483110-chr6_103649291,chrX_143483110-chr6_103649053

it removes last column.

Comment: Looking at your edit, I seem to get the desired output with my given command.

Comment: Ok, now i get it. I have tab separated columns and here you are replacing "space", so i just added sed -E 's/,[^\t]+//g' input.
its working now
thanks for your gentle reply

Comment: You could even handle tabs _and_ spaces with `/,[^ \t]+/` (: